# plone.app.blob RuntimeError while migrating ATFile

Tags: migration, plone, blob, runtime-error

I'm doing a blob migration onto a 3.2.1 site and I'm getting "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error." on some file during @@blob-file-migration.

I found this http://svn.eionet.europa.eu/projects/Zope/ticket/4190 and it looks like they solved this problem for images by creating a custom migrator.

Any clue? Traceback below.

```
  File "/home/simahawk/dev/plone/plone3/projx/src/plone.app.blob/src/plone/app/blob/content.py", line 113, in setFile
    mutator = self.getField('file').getMutator(self)
  File "/home/simahawk/dev/plone/plone3/buildout/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.5.10-py2.4.egg/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py", line 241, in getField
    return self.Schema().get(key)
  File "/home/simahawk/dev/plone/plone3/buildout/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.5.10-py2.4.egg/Products/Archetypes/BaseObject.py", line 828, in Schema
    schema = ISchema(self)
  File "/home/simahawk/dev/plone/plone3/projx/parts/zope2/lib/python/zope/app/component/hooks.py", line 96, in adapter_hook
    return siteinfo.adapter_hook(interface, object, name, default)
  File "/home/simahawk/dev/plone/plone3/buildout/eggs/archetypes.schemaextender-2.1.1-py2.4.egg/archetypes/schemaextender/extender.py", line 143, in cachingInstanceSchemaFactory
    key = IUUID(context, str(id(context)))
  File "/home/simahawk/dev/plone/plone3/projx/parts/zope2/lib/python/zope/app/component/hooks.py", line 96, in adapter_hook
    return siteinfo.adapter_hook(interface, object, name, default)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
2013-03-06 10:16:49 INFO ATCT.migration Rolling back to last safe point
```

Comment: There has been a few blob migration fixes in https://github.com/plone/plone.app.blob/blob/master/CHANGES.rst recently FWIW.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already using p.a.blob from github :S

Comment: In a big installation we get the same error: we fixed it disabling image and file migration during Plone upgrade, the calling migration views later, manually.

Comment: there's no upgrade here, just migration to blobs. that means I'm calling std migration views directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at.schemaextender version (2.1.1). Down-pinning to 1.6.0 solved the issue. This also solved a random KeyError on a 3.3.5 site. I think this is related to [#12051](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12051) and [#11396](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11396). It looks like these are common problems with newer version of at.schemaextender but in the package's README there's no info for Plone 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

When migration from Plone 3.x to Plone 4.x using Products.contentmigration I got teh same error. It seemed there was a bug in plone.app.blob migration. We made this custom migration to bypass the recursion error: http://svn.eionet.europa.eu/projects/Zope/browser/trunk/Products.EEAPloneAdmin/trunk/Products/EEAPloneAdmin/Extensions/ImageFS2Image.py?rev=29656